# Microsoft Graph API get all phonenumbers

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to get a list of all mobile phone numbers from an Azure AD with Microsoft Graph API.

Something like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/phone.number/
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such an API.

You would have to list all the users and then go through them one by one to extract the phone numbers.

You could use the ["List phones" API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profile-list-phones) but that is per user.